# Do Teams questions need the same safeguards to prevent deletion as regular site questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, deletion

Right now, on Teams, the same rules for question deletion seem to be required as on any site (from the [FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for post deletion):

> You can't delete *your own question* when it:
>
> - has an answer with upvotes (even if it has a net negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - has an answer with an awarded bounty

I tried to delete an answered question of mine today and got the same exact series of popups that you get on any site:

The "do you really want to do this":

[image: Deletion confirmation screen. Warning of deletion process and potential for being banned from asking questions.]

I'm pretty sure that the information here isn't correct regarding being blocked from asking questions if you delete answered ones... and if it is - why would it be?

When the post meets one of the bullets above, despite clicking "Delete Question", a red popup appears and chastises you for trying to delete the question:

[image: popup telling you that you can't delete question because others have invested time in it already]

Apparently, this order of events is [intentionally chosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232350/if-i-cant-delete-my-own-question-why-ask-us-for-permission-to-delete-the-quest) to teach users about when deletion is appropriate with the implication that they'd just flag the question for deletion if they couldn't do it themselves... but you can't flag things on Teams, so this isn't really of concern.

So, should this chain of events still be the expected process on Teams? Can/should these popups be adjusted so that they reflect the actual process?

With no deletion privilege or even close voting process (other than duplicates), the Teams infrastructure seems to imply that all questions asked, ever, will be perfectly acceptable for the Team. The only people who can override this are the Admins and there's no way to notify them since there's no flagging. Is this how Teams *should* work?

Comment: I think this is a very valid and cogent question; IMO the warning message is fine, but I'm also inclined to agree that it shouldn't be a hard block. I'll be very interested in what other folks think to this question, and **if people are generally in agreement** (especially my relevant colleagues) I'll be happy to volunteer to implement a teams-specific change here. It is also entirely possible that I'm wrong and the systems should "stand" as-is, and I'm open to that outcome too.

Comment: I genuinely don't know (without checking) whether the answer block applies on "teams"; it probably shouldn't - that's more of an "in-house" issue for team admins.

Comment: @MarcGravell IMO, the same blocks on deletion should be in place by default. It might be reasonable to permit the Team admin to adjust this, but the same reasons about not allowing OP's to delete other people's contributions apply. If the post can't be flagged for Team admin attention, then that's a related, but separate issue. However, the dialogs should be adjusted to present accurate information (e.g. if there's no answer block in Teams, then it shouldn't say there is).

Comment: @Makyen I think part of the issue is that Admins really aren't "moderators" in the sense that diamond mods on SE are. They're not really acting in the same capacity and they don't have the same tools that moderators have (nor, probably, should they). Heck, even the (user) moderation structure of Teams is very... minimal. I hint at it in my question - there's no way to close things other than as duplicates, no flagging, no 10k stuff or 20k delete privileges (regardless of rep level)... as far as I know, there's not even a rep level that lets you *see* deleted posts.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, this really depends on what powers users have within Teams.

- Can some higher privilege user easily *find* deleted questions if they don't have the links?
- Is it easy for some higher privilege user to undelete questions once found?

If the answer to these is no, then delete should have strong restrictions to protect the integrity of the team's knowledge repository. Limit it to users who are in some way trusted; requests to delete must be funneled through them.

Alternatively, SO could build the features in my bullet points, and this would be a better solution, in my opinion. It may be a more costly one, though.

Either way, some mechanism to protect the knowledge repository's information is needed.

Comment: If by "higher privilege" you mean "an Admin", yes. The Admins can use the deleted search function the way a mod can. I don't have any reason to think that undeletion would be more difficult than it is for mods, either. At this point, though, there's no way to assign any other "responsibilities" other than Admins, as far as I'm aware.